# Set local and remote directories to be synced in remote-ftp (Atom package)

Tags: webpack, ftp, vuejs2, atom-editor

I'm using atom editor and [remote-ftp](https://github.com/icetee/remote-ftp) to sync my local files with my shared host.

I'm creating a project with [vue-webpack-boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) which has a

> ./dist

folder for production files.

I want to sync my ./dist folder with server But remote-ftp upload all project files.
I search in remote-ftp documentation but didn't find any solution.

Is there any way to specify a folder to sync with server?
Even with other packages?

**Possible solutions:**

- using .ftpignore : no I can't because still folder itself will upload, I just need it's files not itself.
- change server root to ./dist : It's possible but I don't want to upload all project which has a larger size.

*Sorry about writing problems.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the [`remote-sync`](https://atom.io/packages/remote-sync) package seems to be a better choice, you easily can configure both a local source and a remote target directory:

```
{
    // …
    source: './dist',
    target: '/path/on/server'
}
```